# LINQ query syntax with multiple statements

Tags: c#, linq, linq-query-syntax

Can this method be rewritten using LINQ's query syntax?

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetAllItems()
{
    return Tabs.SelectMany(tab =>
        {
            tab.Pick();
            return tab.Items;
        });
}
```

I cannot figure out where to place `tab.Pick()` method call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, query expressions in LINQ require each selection part etc to be a single expression, not multiple statements.

However, you could write a separate method:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> PickItems(Tab tab)
{
    tab.Pick();
    return tab.Items;
}
```

Then use:

```
var query = from tab in tabs
            from item in PickItems(tab)
            select item.Name;
```

(Or whatever you want to do.)